# Error: No named parameter with the name 'style'

Tags: flutter

Below is a snippet of my code:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Widget buildButton(String buttonText) {
    return Expanded(
      child: new OutlineButton(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
        child: new Text(buttonText),
        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        onPressed: () => {},
      ),
    );
  }
```

I am getting the following error:

```
lib/main.dart:30:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'style'.
      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ^^^^^

Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const OutlineButton({
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I am new to flutter and don't know what is wrong with my style statement.

Comment: you should use editor IntelliJ or VS Code, just hit ctrl+space, it will suggest possible named parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @Nilesh Rathod, the `style` property is in `Text` widget and not in `OutlineButton` widget.

Also avoid using `new` keyword as it is optional. Use trailing commas so that `dartfmt` in IDE will format code for you.

```
  Widget buildButton(String buttonText) {
    return Expanded(
      child: OutlineButton(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
        child: Text(
          buttonText,
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        onPressed: () => {},
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I am not getting the error anymore, but the 'FontWeight' did not change to bold. Any reason why it did not change?

Comment: Try running `flutter clean` and then run the app again. Usually performing a `Hot Restart` resets the state of app and we see the changes.

Answer (score 2):

The `style:TextStyle()` argument is of `Text` widgets not of `OutlineButton` widgets

You need to add `style` argument in `Text` widgets

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Widget buildButton(String buttonText) {
    return Expanded(
      child: new OutlineButton(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
        child: new Text(buttonText,style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
        
        onPressed: () => {},
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I am not getting the error anymore, but the 'FontWeight' did not change to bold. Any reason why it did not change?

Comment: Try to restart the app again